# How to declare a variable that lists all the existing databases on my server with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a variable that lists all the existing databases in my system, because I need it and I don't know how to do it. I have tried to create variables like this one:

```
DECLARE @nombreBD INT;
SET @nombreBD = (SELECT [database_id] FROM sys.databases Where name = 'model' )
SELECT @nombreBD AS Database_ID
PRINT @nombreBD
GO
```

This variable gets me only the name I put in the "WHERE" parameter but I need to get them all.

The table sys.databases shows you all the existing databases in the system and I need to get a boolean value from it, I thought to get it from the column "database_id" that's why I declared this variable.

Comment: Maybe you could describe what your ultimate goal is (*"... get a boolean value from it."*) because it seems like your might be really simple.

Comment: I re-tagged your question to [tag:sql-server] since the query you show does not seem to be related to [tag:mysql] at all.

Comment: You can declare a table variable to hold all the IDs (`DECLARE @nombreBD TABLE (ID INT); INSERT @nombreBD SELECT ...`), but then it's still unclear what you want to do with the results, and why you couldn't also do it in a simple `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a table name `@DBList` with a column `nombreBD`
and inserts the `database_id` to the column,
then it shows all your sql-server database `database_id`

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @DBList TABLE (nombreBD INT)
INSERT INTO @DBList(nombreBD) SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases 
SELECT * FROM @DBList
END
```

Is that what you need ?

Comment: YESS!!!!! Now with that variable I have all the databases listed as if I had an array, but now how can I do that when I put this query, it reads all the databases:USE [BD001] SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName, 'guest' AS Database_User, [permission_name], [state_desc] FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('guest') AND [state_desc] LIKE 'GRANT%' AND [permission_name] = 'CONNECT' AND DB_NAME() NOT IN ('master','tempdb','msdb');It wants that the USE statement is not used...since this only lets me select a DB and I want it to check all of them....

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you will need to use some dynamic SQL.  Something like this ought to work for your case:

```
DECLARE @DBList TABLE (nombre varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @DBList(nombre) SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','tempdb','msdb');

declare @name nvarchar(50);
declare @sql nvarchar(2000);

DECLARE db_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT nombre FROM @DBList;
OPEN db_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_Cursor INTO @name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @sql = N'USE ' + @name + N';'
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
    SET @sql = N'SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName, ''guest'' AS Database_User, [permission_name], [state_desc] 
FROM sys.database_permissions WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'') AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%'' AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT'';';
    exec sp_executesql @sql;

FETCH NEXT FROM db_Cursor INTO @name;
END;
CLOSE db_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_Cursor;
```

Notice that I have changed the table variable to hold the database names, not their ids.  This is because the `USE` statement takes the name not the id.

The cursor loops through the values, builds the various sql statements and executes them.